# assign a given dat to DateTime in Flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter

I have a variable pickedDate that contains a user picked date of the DateTime type. I want to assign that date to the initial FirstDate of another instance that is now set to initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pickedDate is of type DateTime, then you can just set the initialDate of the second instance to that variable.

```
await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: pickedDate, //if pickedDate is type DateTime then this should work
    lastDate: DateTime(2222));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. My user picked date was actually from a List<DateTime> from the Date Range picker but I got it with pickedDate[0]. I was making it more difficult than it was in my mind. Thanks again.